# Why am I having this error on my terminal?

Tags: macos, terminal, jflex

[image]

I am not sure why I am having this one error on my OSX, using terminal, if someone can help?

Comment: Does that file exist at that path?

Comment: Yes, it exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

macOS, like other Unix systems, uses a forward slash `/` as its path separator, not a backslash `\` like Windows. Replace your `\` characters with `/` and it should work.